# Python PIL cannot locate my "libjpeg"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cannot use PIL because it cannot find my libjpeg!

First, I installed PIL default. And when I ran the `selftest.py`, it gave me:

```
IOError: decoder jpeg not available 1
items had failures:    1 of  57 in
selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

Then, I followed instructions online to change PIL's `setup.py` to

```
JPEG_ROOT = "/usr/lib"
```

Because when I `locate libjpeg`, this is what I get:

```
locate libjpeg 
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-6b
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-6b/README
/usr/share/doc/libjpeg-6b/usage.doc
/var/cache/yum/base/packages/libjpeg-6b-37.i386.rpm
/var/cache/yum/base/packages/libjpeg-6b-37.x86_64.rpm
```

So, I ran `setup.py install` again...and did `selftest.py`.
And I still get the same error!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There at least 3 header sets that you will want to install. 1 more if you want to deal with Tiff's

freetype, libjpeg, zlib all of which will be in the following packages on CentOS:

== 32 Bit:
  zlib-devel.i386
  libjpeg-devel.i386
  freetype-devel.i386

== 64 Bit:
  zlib-devel.x86_64
  libjpeg-devel.x86_64
  freetype-devel.x86_64

As you did before you will want to edit the following variables in the setup.py file:

FREETYPE_ROOT
JPEG_ROOT
ZLIB_ROOT

Setting there values to /usr/lib or /usr/lib64 based on your platform. Once done you will most likely want to run

```
python setup.py build --force
python setup.py install
```

That will force rebuild all your lib for PIL and reinstall them raw.

Comment: Thank you! FWIW, this is what I did (on a 64-bit box): `sudo yum install zlib-devel.x86_64 libjpeg-devel.x86_64 freetype-devel.x86_64` then `sudo pip install pil` (This requires you to have pip package manager already installed.)

Answer (score 3):

You need the libjpeg headers as well, not only the library itself. Those packages are typically called something ending in headers or dev, depending on what distribution you have.

Comment: Thanks.
How do I get the headers? 
I have CentOS distribution.
I did "locate libjpeg" and couldn't find anything ending in .headers

Comment: They seem to be called libjpeg-devel on CentOS.

Comment: Use the ‘package management tool’ to install `libjpeg-devel`. Note there may be other `-devel` packages you need to install for other formats, eg. `libpng-devel`.

Comment: I think PIL uses zlib for PNG, if I remember correctly. But I could misremember. It has docs though. :)

Comment: yum install libjpeg-devel - sorted the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case, I need to set:

```
JPEG_ROOT="/usr/lib64/"
```

instead of:

```
JPEG_ROOT="/usr/lib/"
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) instead of PIL.

Pillow is a PIL fork to "foster active development of PIL". In versions 1.7.0 and 1.7.1 they made some changes to support multi-arch (see the [changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0#changelog-pillow)).

Comment: the same problem with Pillow ;( And the solution `JPEG_ROOT="/usr/lib64/"`  does not help for Pillow

Answer (score 0):

Today I was facing the same problem, and I've found the solution. Basically it involves remove the PIL, install lipjpeg through Fink and re-install the PIL.

I wrote an [article](http://marciogarcia.com/?p=289) telling step by step how to do that. If interesting check this out.