# How to get JPEG module working in PIL

Tags: python, compression, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I installed PIL and all the jpeg dependencies for using the `jpeg` module in `PIL`

docs : http://docs.python.org/library/jpeg.html

I want to use the `jpeg.compress()` method stated there. But when i installed PIL i wasn't able to find the `jpeg` module.

can someone tell me how i can use the `jpeg.compress()` method in my script.

Or is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

PIL can be a beast to install at times.  It's very likely it wasn't configured (correctly) with libjpeg.

If it's just a matter of not installing, or PIL not seeing libjpeg, take a look here:

[Python PIL cannot locate my "libjpeg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486157/python-pil-cannot-locate-my-libjpeg-simple-installation-issue)

I'm not sure what platform you're working on, but each seems to have its own set of unique pitfalls when building PIL.  My suggestion is to give "Pillow" a shot, it makes the PIL install process much more user friendly:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

You just need to have a working libjpeg install before running the Pillow install, and you should be off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

The jpeg module and PIL module are independent and have no connection to each other. The documentation lists PIL as a *replacement* for jpeg. You'll need to install the jpeg module separately.